# Is "well-connected" correct here?

Tags: word-usage, expression-choice

I want to use *well-connected* in the context of

> The James family was a well-connected family in ...

Can someone suggest better ways to say it?  I want it to mean that that particular family was well known in the area, was well respected, and had clout.

Answer (score 6):

*Well-connected* seems like a great choice, but you could also try:

***Prominent*** or ***influential*** or a combination of both:

> The James family was a prominent and very influential family in the community...

Comment: I like _influential_, particularly if you want to convery _clout_.

Comment: Good choices, but in both the question and the answer the double usage of "family" bothers me. I'd prefer, "The James family was prominent and very influential in the community..." or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could say the family was a *pillar of the community*. [See definition.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pillar)

*Well-connected* works, too.